# Position the limits of Sum

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathtools

I want the limits of the sum sign to be placed where I placed the red lines in the photo. This is the line of script I used:

```
$Result = p + \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(x)$
```

This is what I get and the red lines is what I want.
[image]

Comment: Use this code: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}$

Comment: unrelated to sum but use `\mathrm{Result}` not `Result` in math mode

Comment: you have my vote; I was wondering if any one could actually express this problem in a easy to understand way, you apparently nailed it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use displaystyle limits in text mode. Which is **not that good,** as I explain below.

I don't know if it's typographically correct but the code is

```
 $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(x)$
```

The `\limits` command allows the limits to be positioned above and below the symbol.

The fact that inline math has "text style" limits is just that inline formulas typeset like display style are usually ugly, disrupt the natural flow of the document (the limits usually create a line whose height and depth is bigger than the other ones), and they are not usually as readable as when they are placed in display.

**Please be cautious when considering what using "displaystyle limits" in text mode.**

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you didn't use `displaymath` operators (`$$...$$` or `\[...\]`; I recommend the latter). If you want such a structure in inline math, you must use `\limits`. By implementing my solution (with `displaymath`) we get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ \text{Result} = p + \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(x) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

My solution for inline math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

Hello. Inline math is one of my favourites. Isn't \LaTeX wonderful? By simply adding $\mathtt{limits}$, we can force the symbols to move upwards. I don't recommend its usage in inline mode, as it makes the $\mathtt{sum}$ symbol too small and occasionally forces the space between lines to stretch, which uglifies everything. Ayway, here is the result: Result $= p + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} f(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]